# Kafka - collect logs from multiple servers. Should each producer running on write to the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am learning to use Kafka. I would like to implement a centralized log service using Kafka. I have multiple servers running my application, I would like my application to write their log to Kafka (i.e producers) and then a consumer on the other side to read the logs back. I would like to use the same topic for all my applications. For example, I would like my application to write to a topic called "AppLog" and then have the consumer just read the AppLog topic back.

Does Kafka support multiple producers writing to the same topic?

Note: The relative sequences of the log does not matter to me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look [here](http://kafka.apache.org/07/performance.html) you'll see that having even 40 producers for 1 topic does not affect performance that much, so yes, you may use multiple producers to write into one topic.

Comment: @serejja what's the maximum limit on no. of producers for a single topic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many producers as you want writing to the same topic. To improve parallelism you can scale your topic increasing the number of partitions and use more brokers (Kafka servers) in your cluster.